# How to convert amount in crores to decimal value in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a price list of my product like this `Rs 148573769277.60 (Rs 14857.38 crores)` in xslt.

if i have amount `818354941.60` then i want to convert into this **Rs 81.84 (Crores)** ([Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system))

How to this do in xslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:variable name="orignumber" select="'Rs 148573769277.60'"/>
    <!-- filter only the numbers and the '.' from the text -->
    <xsl:variable name="number" select="translate($orignumber, translate($orignumber, '0123456789,.', ''), '')"/>
    <!-- this sets the format to 2 decimals - the multiplication is based on your text. -->
    <!-- concat just adds your chosen text(unit) to the number/string -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Rs ', format-number(number($number) * 0.0000000001,'##.##'), ' (Crores)')"/>
</fo:block>
```

Alternative you can filter just the numbers and set the '.' by yourself.